# What do Philosophers think about the Many Worlds Interpretation of quantum mechanics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics, quantum-physics

One of the interpretations of quantum mechanics is the [Many Worlds Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) which basically states that the universe as a whole develops like an unobserved quantum system, and any observation effects ("collapse of the wave function") are illusions which are caused by the observer getting entangled with the observed system, which effectively causes a split of his world into many worlds, one for each measurement outcome.

Most physicists are against this theory because those other worlds are, by definition, unobservable, and thus violate the common positivist view. However I'd be interested in what philosophers (especially non-positivist ones) think about that interpretation. Is it philosophically sound, or does it have fundamental problems?

Comment: Since these other worlds are unobservable, the question of whether or not they exist is moot. A thing which exists but which cannot be observed has the same effects and influence as something which doesn't exist at all.

Comment: I suspect if such many universes outcomes are possible, then each of the units (in terms of quanta, atoms, protons,neutrons, electrons, quarks etc.) of mass undergoing observation symmetry breaking, i.e where the state of the system diverges from superposition to simultaneous distinct outcomes, has a universe of its own. Bot I do not think this is true myself though. I used to a believer pf many universes too, but there is a flaw somewhere in it I think.

Comment: Plenty of philosophies have dreamt of other worlds than jsut the world we live in, but they're not backed by such heavy mathematical/physical formalism. Which may or may not be an advantage depending on your point of view.

Comment: The many worlds interpretation in my opinion fails to address the fact that we only are conscious of one alternative and not the whole multiverse of alternatives. This is a serious draback of the interpretation. In other words collapse seems real

Comment: Check "The fabric of reality" by David Deutch

Comment: They think it shows the irrational nature of many scientists. 3 Interpretive challenges
4 Influential interpretations
4.1 Copenhagen interpretation
4.2 Many worlds
4.3 Quantum information theories
4.4 Relational quantum mechanics
4.5 QBism
4.6 Consistent histories
4.7 Ensemble interpretation
4.8 De Broglie–Bohm theory
4.9 Quantum Darwinism
4.10 Transactional interpretation
4.11 Objective collapse theories
4.12 Von Neumann–Wigner interpretation
4.13 Quantum logic
4.14 Modal interpretations of quantum theory
4.15 Time-symmetric theories
4.16 Other interpretations

Comment: I like the MWI in re QM. I have no beef with Copenhagenians though. Philosophers? 

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of metaphysics and quantum physics is the best place to be! There are so many interesting questions about the nature of reality that are posed in modern quantum physics. Just as you've stubbled on, one of this problems of philosophy of physics is the Many Worlds Interpretation.

My sense (I'm an undergrad, so take this for what you will) is that your general scientific realists and determinists (not mutually exclusive) will not be in favor of the Many Worlds Interpretation. I say this for two reasons: (1) [quantum logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/) is a very new field and (2) the interpretation itself has some interesting metaphysical consequences.

To elaborate on the second point, to assume that the interpretation is true and that an infinite number of possible worlds are generated by each individual decisions that individuals make (ignoring the more complex problem of event occurrences and just focusing on choice). To allow for an interpretation that presents within itself a plurality of possibilities for the next 10 seconds, let alone the next 10 years, increases the importance of any individual choice. My decision to wear jeans instead of khakis may be a decision that is required to lead to World War III happening in 2050 rather than in 3000. Still you run into *ex post facto*
bias.

This probably isn't the greatest explanation (as it lacks all specificity to appeal to a more general audience), but its just one undergrad's opinion :)

Answer (score -1):

According to the PBR theorem, since the quantum wavefunction has been directly measured as a real physical object, the vision of the universe no longer can be considered psi-epimestic (merely information contained in the quantum wavefunction). The possible remained alternatives are psi-ontics (real objects outside our conciousness) or psi-ontic-epistemics (information with an objective underlying reality) Thus, the Copenhagen interpretation was shifted in favour of the Many Worlds Interpretation (MWI). In MWI you can imagine yourself living in infinite copies of yourself, one for each possible universe, with infinite outcomes. Therefore, if in this universe you are the Dalai Lama, then in another universe you are Adolf Hitler. In my humble opinion, that's one more reason to believe that quantum mechanics theory should not be extended to our common macro reality and our human beliefs, otherwise we risk to fall into an absolute relativism and our life could stick to just a random nonsense. That's why I blame quantum mysticism or, in general, theories which want to merge science and religion. Nevertheless, science is falsifiable, as stated by Karl Popper. Thus, even quantum religions should be forced to review their statements, and that is a nonsense too. That's why I do not trust too much New Age an other quantum woo beliefs.

Comment: There are at least some serious scientists who support MWI, the most public of whom is probably Sean Carroll. There is plenty of pseudo-science around the topic for sure, but I don't think you can simply label all MWI proponents as new age quantum woo salesmen. I doubt very much that Sean Carroll would agree with your characterisation that MWI means that somewhere there is a universe where you are the Dalai Lama and another where you are Hitler.

Comment: @RisingMaverick: David Deutsch is another MWI advocate, & a foundational thinker in the field of quantum computing who really couldn't have a stronger academic pedigree (Cambridge Math Tripos pt 3, & leading Oxford professor)

Comment: I had an opportunity to ask Sean Carroll a question about MWI, and his answer did shake my own belief in the reality of it. I asked Carroll, "can you approximate the rate that the universe splits"? His answer was "Continuously." Not once a second or once a week but as a continuous flow. This adds a whole new dimension to the idea.